# Can different policy iteration methods converge to different optimal policies?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

For example, I have tried to run lambda iteration iteration on a random MDP. I noticed getting different policies depending on the value of lambda. Can TD(1) and TD(0) give different optimal policies?

Update: Increasing my initial value function gave me the same result for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general, RL methods with convergence guarantees can converge to any optimal policy. So, if an MDP has several optimal policies, algorithms (including *Policy iteration* methods) could converge to any of the optimal policies.